# How to use angular material List

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to display a list of item inside a Selection lists. This list represent all of possible value of an object. I want to pre-check the existing value contains in this object.

if my object is "foo".
Then i want that all value in foo.items are pre-check inside the list of items.

template.html

```
 <mat-selection-list #itemList>
    <h3 mat-subheader>Items</h3>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of items"> {{items.name}} </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.url.subscribe(url => {

  this.itemService.findAll().subscribe(items => {
    this.items = items;
  });

  const options: string[] = [];
  options['include'] = 'items';
  this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.fooService.findById(params['id'], options))
    .subscribe((item) => {
      this.foo = foo;
    });
});
```

What i need to do handle this? Documentation is very succint

Answer (score 0):

i got it working like so :

```html
<mat-selection-list #filterList name="filterList" [(ngModel)]="filter" ngDefaultControl>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let option of filterOptions" value="{{ option.value }}">
    {{ option.title }}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterList.selectedOptions.onChange.subscribe(item => {
      item.added.map(added => this.filters.push(added.value));
      item.removed.map(removed => this.filters = this.filters.filter((val: any) => {
        return val !== removed.value;
      }));
    });
  }
```